# Store the whole graph

Tags: tensorflow

I found a interesting project on github which recognize face in realtime:
https://github.com/vudung45/FaceRec

In that project there are two part, the face detection and the face recognition. The two graph are stored in a global graph and I want to export that global graph.

I add that code in mtcnn_detect.py:

```
    def __init__(self, face_rec_graph, model_path = "models", threshold = [0.6, 0.7, 0.7], factor = 0.709, scale_factor = 1):
    '''
    :param face_rec_sess: FaceRecSession
    :param threshold: detection threshold
    :param factor: default 0.709 image pyramid -- magic number
    :param model_path:
    '''
    self.threshold = threshold
    self.factor = factor
    self.scale_factor = scale_factor;
    with face_rec_graph.graph.as_default():
        print("Loading MTCNN Face detection model")
        self.sess = tf.Session()
        if not model_path:
            model_path, _ = os.path.split(os.path.realpath(__file__))

        with tf.variable_scope('pnet'):
            data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, None, None, 3), 'input')
            pnet = PNet({'data': data})
            pnet.load(os.path.join(model_path, 'det1.npy'), self.sess)
        with tf.variable_scope('rnet'):
            data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 24, 24, 3), 'input')
            rnet = RNet({'data': data})
            rnet.load(os.path.join(model_path, 'det2.npy'), self.sess)
        with tf.variable_scope('onet'):
            data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 48, 48, 3), 'input')
            onet = ONet({'data': data})
            onet.load(os.path.join(model_path, 'det3.npy'), self.sess)

        self.pnet = lambda img: self.sess.run(('pnet/conv4-2/BiasAdd:0', 'pnet/prob1:0'), feed_dict={'pnet/input:0': img})
        self.rnet = lambda img: self.sess.run(('rnet/conv5-2/conv5-2:0', 'rnet/prob1:0'), feed_dict={'rnet/input:0': img})
        self.onet = lambda img: self.sess.run(('onet/conv6-2/conv6-2:0', 'onet/conv6-3/conv6-3:0', 'onet/prob1:0'),
                                        feed_dict={'onet/input:0': img})
        print("MTCNN Model loaded")


        ###############what I added #################
        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/tmp/model3/", face_rec_graph.graph)
        saver = tf.train.Saver() #saver load pretrain model
        save_path = saver.save(self.sess, "/tmp/model3/model.ckpt")
        print("Model saved in path: %s" % save_path)
```

When I launch the program I get that error:

```
MTCNN Model loaded



Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1323, in _do_call
        return fn(*args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1302, in _run_fn
        status, run_metadata)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
        c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value InceptionResnetV1/Block8/Branch_0/Conv2d_1x1/BatchNorm/beta
         [[Node: save_1/SaveV2 = SaveV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save_1/Const_0_0, save_1/SaveV2/tensor_names, save_1/SaveV2/shape_and_slices, InceptionResnetV1/Block8/Branch_0/Conv2d_1x1/BatchNorm/beta, InceptionResnetV1/Block8/Branch_0/Conv2d_1x1/BatchNorm/moving_mean, InceptionResnetV1/Block8/Branch_0/Conv2d_1x1/BatchNorm/moving_variance, InceptionResnetV1/Block8/Branch_0/Conv2d_1x1/weights, InceptionResnetV1/Block8/Branch_1/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/beta, InceptionResnetV1/Block8/Branch_1/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/moving_mean, InceptionResnetV1/Block8/Branch_1/Conv2d_0a_1x1/BatchNorm/moving_variance, InceptionResnetV1/Block8/Branch_1/Conv2d_0a_1x1/weights, InceptionResnetV1/Block8/Branch_1/Conv2d_0b_1x3/BatchNorm/beta, InceptionResnetV1/Block8/Branch_1/Conv2d_0b_1x3/BatchNorm/moving_mean, InceptionResnetV1/Block8/Branch_1/Conv2d_0b_1x3/BatchNorm/moving_variance,


....


Caused by op 'save_1/SaveV2', defined at:
  File "./main.py", line 156, in <module>
    face_detect = MTCNNDetect(FRGraph, scale_factor=2); #scale_factor, rescales image for faster detection
  File "/home/xavier/Téléchargements/FaceRec-master/mtcnn_detect.py", line 51, in __init__
    saver = tf.train.Saver() #saver load pretrain model
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1218, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1227, in build
    self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1263, in _build
    build_save=build_save, build_restore=build_restore)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 748, in _build_internal
    save_tensor = self._AddSaveOps(filename_tensor, saveables)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 296, in _AddSaveOps
    save = self.save_op(filename_tensor, saveables)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 239, in save_op
    tensors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 1163, in save_v2
    shape_and_slices=shape_and_slices, tensors=tensors, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1470, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
```

Edit:

As Peter Szoldan advice me in his poste, I add for the moment an initialize variable parts.

I add the result in tensorboard view. My question is why is there an auxiliary part in the graph? Why are all the nodes in the same main graph?

[image]

Comment: Looks like `InceptionResnetV1/Block8/Branch_0/Conv2d_1x1/BatchNorm/beta` doesn't get initialized.

Have you tried running the network for faces and does it work?

Comment: Yes When I remove the save part I added, the program works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `InceptionResnetV1/Block8/Branch_0/Conv2d_1x1/BatchNorm/beta` doesn't get initialized.

As a quick fix, you can [initialize all unitialized](http://Looks%20like%20InceptionResnetV1/Block8/Branch_0/Conv2d_1x1/BatchNorm/beta%20doesn't%20get%20initialized.) variables before saving, that will let the save go through.

Still, it is probably advisable to go into the details of your networks and see why this is the case. Maybe `center=True` wasn't the default setting in [`tf.layers.batch_normalization()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/batch_normalization) when the network was designed, and they didn't have the beta saved? Just guessing.

Comment: thanks you for the answer. I seems you put link I can access "initialize all unitialized". I will try the other solution I will tell you if it works